# How do I highlight speech discrepancies?

Tags: papers-please

This person came to the border today. He claimed he was visiting, but his permit was for permanent immigration. I tried to highlight the issue but...

[image: Screenshot]

Figuring that a visit is something that a permanent immigration permit would obviously allow, I let him through. Makes sense right? [Wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD6FN.png)

What should I have done here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to click *precisely* onto the text. (In your case the `IMMIGRATE` on the entry permit)

Like this:

[image]
Sometimes the click registers just outside the text, and therefore registers on the entire document. Which, obviously, isn't specific enough.

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: Game releases - Giving me a late Enlightened badge since 2013!